# Lightning - a lost transaction

Tags: lightning-network

I would like to understand if there is a way to loose a transaction received over the payment channel.

What is a mechanism for keeping track of all the transactions occurred in a channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the parties in the channel need to keep track of what transactions happened in the channel; they are not broadcast publicly. They keep track of this by using a database local to the wallet only.